# How to Copy Projects in Project Web App for Office 365

Tags: project, office365, ms-project

Once a Project is uploaded/Created in Project Web App on Office 365, how can that project be duplicated or copied, and renamed to form a new and separate project?

Or does a brand new file have to be uploaded to Sharepoint if we want to start a new project from an existing template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Talking to Microsoft Tech Support over the phone, we learned that **it is impossible to duplicate or rename a Project from within Project web app for Office 365.**

The only option is to Start a new project from scratch, or import one from a PC that has Project Professional installed locally.

Sorry Mac users - MS Project doesn't exist for mac, so you have to rely on your PC toting peers to upload new documents for you - This is dumb, since most of our team uses Macs. We originally planned to use Project Web App to make our Project files for 300+ Clients. Knowing now that we can't just Upload a single template Project and Save as new... Now we have to rely on a single PC user to upload the same template 300+ times, so that we can each pick a specific template instance and edit it    :(